# Porting multiple windows scheduled tasks from a VM to a single web job

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, webjob

I'm reasonably new to Azure and I'm just wanting to confirm I'm on the right track when wanting to port multiple windows scheduled tasks to web jobs.

Currently I deploy my (c#) project to a single directory on a VM, and have a series of scheduled tasks that run on various schedules, using scheduled task arguments to determine what task gets run.

I would like to port this to web jobs (or any other relevant Azure serverless app) but the only way I see it working is creating a single web job per scheduled job. This will be a real pain when making code changes and having to deploy to 20-30 different locations (one per web job).

Is there a way of doing this that give me the equivalent of multiple windows schedules tasks running the same exe? I was thinking possibly having a settings.job file with multiple schedules and each schedule having optional arguments, but it doesn't look like this is possible.

Is the only way to skin this to create a separate web job per scheduled task and then copy the code up to each web job directory, or am I missing an easier way?

Thanks for any help on this

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples over at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples can give you a basic idea. But from what you've said, I think you can add different scheduled triggers (Timer, Queue) in a `Functions.cs` that's added your C# console project. Check out this [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) guide as well in addition to reviewing the BasicSamples repo.

When it comes to your task arguments, I would look at using Azure Storage Tables and [bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table?tabs=csharp) the table to your `[TimerTrigger]` to pull the argument data so the "function" knows what to do.

You can [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#deploy-to-azure-app-service) your project as a webjob and each trigger in `Functions.cs` should show up under the Web Jobs blade of App Service you deployed to.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Ryan. I was trying to do this in config, but after reading your comments it makes sense to have multiple timertriggers in a Function.cs